# Background picture in animation

Tags: animation

Im trying to make an animation like universal, but I don´t know how to put a backgroud picture that doesn´t shows the same all the time. For example, in the intro of universal the stars on the background change when the camera focuses in a different direction. someone knows how to do it? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a skybox, or skydome https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybox_%28video_games%29
or even a simple *Import Image as Plane* and warp it a bit, if you don't need a full 360.